# Golang http client read headers async

Tags: http, asynchronous, go, client

I have some http service which sends headers showing progress while preparing response.

So it looks like
X-progress: 10%
X-progress: 20% (after some time)
...
X-progress: 100% (after more time)

And only after that it start sending the response body.

Is there a way to get that progress info in golang http client? Kinda OnHeaderArrived callback?

I can do it on low level just with simple TCP client but it means i will need to reimplement a lot of HTTP protocol stuff. May there is a way to use net/http above custom Dial connection?

Comment: There is no hook for this because headers are expected to be received in one group. This is quite unusual behavior from a server, and most client libraries will have fairly short timeouts for receiving just the headers.

Comment: If it's possible to change the clients, you can implement the desired effect [using the response's payload (body) instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46891608/720999).

Comment: Unfortunately i can't change the server. Now thinking about reading the raw data from a connection and after header is finished - pass the processing to golang HTTP parser.

Comment: So i mean to read the raw HTTP resp to some buffer till new line will arrive and afterward pass the buffer with header and original io buffer with body to http/response using io/multi,

Comment: As an other option make some local proxy.