# sending multiple responses to client

Tags: go

I have a web client and a Go server. The client send some json data, which is processed and the server then return a json response.

But what can I do when I want to inform the client about the results of a very slow process, and even allow the client to stop the process?

I've been thinking maybe I could keep sending new requests every 5-10 seconds for updates, but that doesn't seem very efficient, and it wouldn't allow me to stop a process I started using `go mySlowFunc()`

Comment: Unless you have an example of where you're having a problem implementing a solution in Go, this isn't really relevant to Go.

Comment: [Here's one way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46891608/720999).

Comment: you can use websockets to keep a full duplex open channel between client and server where you can send from client to server and vice versa. usually you can use this for pushing update progress to client

Comment: If the client is a web browser, then polling and websockets are your best options.   SSE is an option if you [don't need to support Microsoft's browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource).   Is the client a web browser, or something else?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I already use a REST API. It sounds like the best/easiest option for me would be to send a unique ID back to the client that can be used to poll with.

Answer (score 0):

You may create some “guards” for slow functions. They limit execution time, of function succeeded during this time they return result, if not - default value is returned and function is cancelled.

Example of code:

```
select {
case result := <-successChan:
    return result, nil
case <-timeoutChan:
    return "", nil
}
```

Example of usage: https://github.com/lisitsky/go-site-search-string